# Understanding the expected value in this particular example

Tags: probability, expected-value

At MOP, there are $n$ people, each of who has a name tag. We
shuffle the name tags and randomly give each person one of the name tags.
Let S be the number of people who receive their own name tag. Prove that
the expected value of $S$ is $1$.

Let $P_i$ denote the person number $i$, and $T_i$ denote the name tag that belongs to $P_i$ finally, $\mathbb{P}(P_i=T_i)$ is the probability that $P_i$ got his name tag. My guess is that since the shuffling was random we can assume $\mathbb{P}(P_i=T_i)=1/n$ Hence, $$\mathbb E[S]=\sum_{x}\mathbb{P}(P_x=T_x)\cdot x=\frac{1}{n}\cdot \frac{n(n+1)}{2}=\frac{(n+1)}{2}?$$
Am I lacking something about the expected value?

Comment: $\frac 1 n$ is not the probability of $x$ people having a match. $\mathbb E[S]=\sum_{x}\mathbb{P}(P_x=T_x) \cdot 1$

Comment: $\mathbb{E}[S]$ should just be $\sum\limits_{x}\mathbb{P}(P_x =T_x)$, not $\sum\limits_{x}\mathbb{P}(P_x =T_x)\cdot x$.

Comment: Then what is $1/n$? @MathLover

Comment: Probability of _a_ person having a match and by linearity of expectation the answer comes to $n \cdot \frac 1 n = 1$